# QGIS link values longer than the links?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

Can you please help me to correct link rapresentation when the thickness exceed the links.
In the image you can see the value on two consecutive links that generate a bad view.
I think it depends on the thickness linked to the offset, but I am not able to solve it.
With offset=0 I have no problem, but I need to set the offset to put the value on the driving side. Thanks[image: you can see the error in the red cirle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line style options, there is an option for **flat caps**. Change from the default square caps to flat and it should look much better.

Comment: That's it!The question is solved, I will insert the image with the solution soon. Thanks